# How to avoid using "extern" to share an instance between many files in C?

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I made a timer library in c to start a timer, stop it ...etc. I use this lib for making many timers for different events. For each event I should make a new instance of the timer. I use one with serial communication library and one for the keypad library. Now the point is that there is a function `timer_interrupt_handler(New_timer* timer)` that must be called for each instance by the microcontroller's timer1 interrupt routine which remains in the main file. For this, timers' instances must be of extern type. Is there a way to avoid using extern in this scenario.

timer_tick.h file

```
typedef enum state{STOPPED=0, RUNNING, TIMEOUT} Timer_state;

typedef struct {
        unsigned char volatile state;
        unsigned int volatile ticks;
        unsigned int volatile timeout_ticks;
    }New_timer;
```

timer_tick.c file

```
#include "timer_tick.h"

void start_a_timer(New_timer* timer)
{
    timer->state = RUNNING;
    timer->ticks = 0;
}

void stop_a_timer(New_timer* timer)
{
    timer->state = STOPPED;
}

void timer_interrupt_handler(New_timer* timer)
{
    if(timer->state==RUNNING)
    {
        if(timer->ticks < timer->timeout_ticks)
            timer->ticks++;
        else
            timer->state = TIMEOUT;
    }
}
```

main.c

```
// timer1 interrupt routine
void timerIsr()
{
    timer_interrupt_handler(&timer1);
    timer_interrupt_handler(&timer2);
    timer_interrupt_handler(&timer3);
    timer_interrupt_handler(&timer4);
    timer_interrupt_handler(&timer5);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps dole out `N` indexes: `timer_interrupt_handler(&timer1);` --> `timer_interrupt_handler(0);` and have `timer_interrupt_handle()` look up the `New_timer[0]`

Comment: Going off of what chux said, maybe make a function create_a_timer that initializes a timer into a stopped condition and then stores each timer in a null-terminated list of timers?

Comment: So, how do you use it now? I don't see any `extern` in what you posted. And what is the problem with `extern` anyway? Why do you want to avoid using it?

Comment: Your question is worded confusingly.  "extern" is just a keyword used to share variables between different compilation units.  It is not a type.  I think what you are really asking is: how can I have timers that are only visible in one compilation unit but still receive service in the ISR by the timer library.

Comment: @AnT Like I said, the extern timers are defined in another libraries. I want to avoid using extern for data encapsulation.

Comment: @David Grayson, Yes maybe you are right. To make the point clear I shared the .c .h files.

Comment: @old_timer: You got it backwards. *In theory* globals with the same name are *errors* in standard C. That's how it has been in C from the very first standard (C89). However, *in practice* these errors are "forgiven" by most compilers as an extension, because back in the day it used to be supported by pre-standard UNIX compilers. So, if you want to write standard-conforming C code you cannot just declare globals with the same name. You have to make sure you have only one definition, and make the rest pure declarations with `extern`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  from turbo to borland to zortech to watcom to microsoft to gnu over time the behavior was most definitely not consistent.

Comment: Does C89 imply 1989?  Awefully late for a language from the 60s.

Comment: @old_timer: "Language from the 60" was dramatically different from standard C (or from K&R C), even in terms of plain syntax. Also, the stricter definition model was actually first adopted by K&R C, which appeared way before 1989.

Comment: yep, I was sorta poking fun at history.  although mainstream in some circles (unix) for decades.  In the 80s we had the everyone can own their own computer and shortly thereafter everyone can afford their own compiler for that computer, leading to the (assembly vs) pascal vs C battle on those platforms which went the way of C and created many new programmers and a really good idea to try to standardize the language that had been floating about for a decade or two.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you register the instances in the timer module using a linked list?

At client code

```
static New_timer a_timer;
void foo () {
    timer_register (&a_timer);
};
```

At timer.c:

```
void timer_register (New_timer * timer) {
    timer_add_to_a_linked_list (timer);
}

void timer_interrupt_handler () {
    for_each_timer_in_list_do_something ();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this would work.  The timers themselves can hold the links that make the linked list.  The timer library just needs to hold a pointer to the first timer, and that will link to the next timer in the list, and so on.

Comment: I often implement such timer drivers with linked lists too. For timers that aren't critical, this is a good solution. The only down-side is that if you have hard real-time requirements, you cannot and should not use this method, because linked lists are not random access, and timers at the end of the list will face a slight bit more latency.

Comment: @Felipe Lavratti, For this solution I have to store the timers in the dynamic memory right?

Comment: @Lundin, For hard real-time requirements what is your approach to solve such a problem?

Comment: @Majid_L A linked list can be used for any kind of memory. You most definitely do not want to use heap memory in an embedded system. Simply use statically allocated data for the memory pool. Each module using the timer driver allocates that memory together with the timer struct.

Comment: @Majid_L For hard real-time requirements, use designated timers for each task and don't attempt a generic solution. You would also prefer as few interrupts as possible. The ideal is to setup the timer with pre-scalers so that there is only one interrupt, when the timer has elapsed.

Comment: @Majid_L no. Avoid heap. Use the linkedlist approach where you have a next field in the New_timer struct. Google for linkedlists in C.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the use of `extern` in many cases by the use of a *getter* function.

In client.h:

```
#include "timer_tick.h"

New_timer* client_get_timer(void);
```

In client.c:

```
#include "client.h"

New_timer local_timer;

New_timer* client_get_timer()
{
    return &local_timer;
}
```

In main.c:

```
#include "client.h"

void timerIsr()
{
    timer_interrupt_handler(client_get_timer());
}
```

Comment: This is applicable for just one instance. What if I had many timers?

Comment: You would create a local New_timer variable for each timer you need, and a getter function for each one.